# Confused for configuring mail server (Exim)

Tags: email, smtp

I would like to setup an outgoing SMTP server on my server. My ISP blocks port 25, so, I've read I must use relay host (likely my ISP smtp server).
I want the recipient to see the sender email as `user@mydomain.tld`.

If I understood correctly, here is the scheme I would follow for mail delivery :
`Sendmail -> Exim -> ISP relay -> recipient`

So my first question is, do I really need Exim server ?
If I need it, I'm confused with Router and Transport configurations, how it works ?

Finally, If in the future I want to be able to receive mail sent to `user@domain.tld`, what sort scheme should I follow ?

**EDIT**
I not currently plan to receive replies. I want to setup an outgoing only solution. Mostly used by Nextcloud to send notifications and `sendmail` command for server maintenance notification too.

I don't know SPF, DMARC and DKIM. I've googled a bit and it looks like it related to the domain name configuration. So, it would not be a problem if have to configure something there.

Comment: Before you start sending email, consider where you want replies to be delivered. The answer to that helps define the answer to the question you've asked

Comment: Do you want to provide SPF and DMARC indications? What about DKIM?

Comment: In the process flow line you start with `Sendmail`. Do you mean the `sendmail` application or are you simply indicating "_I want to send an email at this point_"?

Comment: Thanks you for your comments @roaima.
I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Ok. If you're using `sendmail` you don't need `exim` (or `postfix` for that matter). You only need one Mail Transport Agent (MTA). You might be best off simply routing through Google, and there's plenty of documentation on that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @roaima for your help.

For outgoing emails only, I don't need `postfix` or `exim` server. I can simply use the `sendmail` command to route my emails through Google or my ISP smtp server.
With the `sendmail` daemon, I could also use it to send emails from my various services such as Nextcloud.